# Flatten elastic search _source output

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I have a problem using Elastic Search (ES) to retrieve JSON object. Right now, when I tried to use below request body to query some data from ES,

```
"_source": [
    "data.id",
    "data.completed",
    "data.label",
    "data.url",
    "data.mobile"
],

"query": {
    ...
}
```

I always get response in form of

```
{
    "took": 225,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        ...
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            ...
        },
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": [
            {
                ...

                "_source": {
                    "data": {
                        "mobile": 1,
                        "label": "EU Mobile Test",
                        "completed": 1582990420,
                        "id": "2002",
                        "url": "http://www.example.com/"
                    }
                },

                ...
            },


          ...
        ]
    }
}
```

Is there a way that I could retrieve JSON children information directly via request body? so that the response to be something like:

```
 {
    "took": 225,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        ...
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            ...
        },
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": [
            {
                ...

                "_source": {
                        "mobile": 1,
                        "label": "EU Mobile Test",
                        "completed": 1582990420,
                        "id": "2002",
                        "url": "http://www.example.com/"
                },

                ...
            },


          ...
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: May I ask you the reason for that? What is the problem you are going to solve?

Comment: Im trying to visualize the data returned by Elastic Search with Redash.
But Redash seems no able to recognize the 1st type of data format.

Comment: How the Elasticsearch response is fed into Redash?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the way the `_source` attribute in a `hit` is structured, except for limiting what's returned by using `_source`, like you did.

---

You can hack around using, say, scripted fields:

```json
GET biao/_search
{
  "_source": "extracted_data",
  "script_fields": {
    "extracted_data": {
      "script": {
        "source": """
        def map = [:];
        for (def field : params['data_fields']) {
          try {
            map[field] = doc['data.' + field].value;  
          } catch(Exception e){
            try {
              map[field] = doc['data.' + field + '.keyword'][0];  
            } catch(Exception ee) {
              
            }
          }
        }
        return map;
          
        """,
        "params": {
          "data_fields": [
            "mobile",
            "label",
            "completed",
            "id",
            "url"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

yielding

```json
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "biao",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : { },
        "fields" : {
          "extracted_data" : [
            {
              "mobile" : 1,
              "label" : "EU Mobile Test",
              "completed" : 1582990420,
              "id" : "2002",
              "url" : "http://www.example.com/"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

but now you have a new problem because you'll need to access data with `fields.extracted_data[0]` ;).

Read the redash docs again -- there must be a cleaner way of doing this!